# PHP - Удалить из строки повторяющуюся подстроку

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на PHP можно удалить повторяющуюся подстроку из строки. К примеру, есть строка "вр-88-72вр-88-72". Дублирующуюся подстроку "вр-88-72" нужно удалить, чтобы осталась только подстрока"вр-88-72". Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Пополам строку поделите, либо добавьте еще примеров и ваши варианты реализации и небольшое пояснение, что не получилось.

Comment: Поделить строку пополам оказалось хорошей идеей, спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace('/(.+)\1/iU','$1','вр-88-72вр-88-72');
```

Где:

```
(.+) - любые символы
\1 - дубликат того, что нашлось в скобочках
$1 - то, что нашлось в скобочках, только для раздела замены, а не паттерна.
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]